# Java regex to split text in first line and all remaining lines

Tags: java, regex, string, multiline

Given a multiline text string consisting of several lines (including blank ones), what would be the most efficient regex to

1. Fully match the string, and
2. Split the string in 2 groups, consisting of the first line and everything that follows, respectively?

Trying a simple expression like

```
(?m)(.*)((?:\s|.)*)
```

does not work beyond a certain string length (just a few hundred characters), causing a stack overflow (!). Many variations afterwards, the same issue persists...

Comment: Why not just find the index of the first newline character \n and then use substring to get 2 new strings?

Comment: Because of the use case, ti has to be a regex, with exactly 2 groups, i.e. the first line and all remaining lines. It seems easy to describe, at least. :-)

Comment: There was an answer by the user "hwnd" which got very close but for some reason he has deleted it. Anyway, I made a couple of slight modifications and the improved regex seems to work. The modified regex that work is `(.*)(?:\r|\n)*((?s).*)` and it covers even strings that have only 1 line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you must use a regular expression, but if you need to split it up into two groups, I would match everything up until possible newline sequences and then everything afterwards ...

```
(.*)[\r\n]*((?s).*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Split with limit can do this easily

```
String[] a = str.split("\\R", 2);
```

Comment: The requirement was for a regex. This is fed to a library that does the processing, so there is no option to run any other Java code. Thanks and +1 for the sugestion.